# how to create an enum of sorting strategies

Tags: c#, sorting, enums

I'm trying to write a sorting method that would receive both the collection and the sorting strategy.

I could simply receive an IComparer but I would prefer to have an enumeration of possible sorting strategies. The callers would have to pick theirs from there.

Something like:

```
public enum SortingStrategies { ByAgeDesc, ByAgeAsc, ByIncomeDesc, ByInconmeAsc };
```

Each of those (ByAgeDesc, ByAgeAsc...) would be an IComparer.

Then calling the sorting method would be:

```
myObject.SortCollection(myCollection, SortingStrategies.ByIncomeDesc);
```

Is is possible to create an enum of instances? Is it a good idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not only possible, but perfectly viable (that is, *if* you think through all possible using scenarios to prevent incompatible collection-sorting method couplings)

Comment: Sure, it gives you strong-typing for the sorting method you want to use.  But you're going to end up with a `switch` statement to equate your `enum` value to whichever `IComparer` you want to use.

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? LINQ with lamba expressions are pretty readable and easy to figure out whats happening. Plus from a maintainability standpoint you dont have to edit the sort routines if more fields are added to the object

Comment: @Yuck Totally agree, you could write this as an answer I think.

Comment: @Yuck Thx, that switch is what I was trying to avoid. I guess the static class the IComparer implementations is the best way to go (was my default option but got curious about the enum...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use a straight enum for this. I'd create a bunch of `IComparer<T>` implementations to pick from:

```
public static class SortingStrategy
{
    public static readonly IComparer<Person> ByAgeDescending = ...;
    public static readonly IComparer<Person> ByAgeAscending = ...;
    public static readonly IComparer<Person> ByIncomeDescending = ...;
    public static readonly IComparer<Person> ByIncomeAscending = ...;
}
```

... or quite possibly use composition to do the ascending/descending part (e.g. via an extension method on `IComparer<T>` to create a reversing wrapper).

Now this doesn't *force* the caller to use one of your predefined values, of course. You could force it by using your own class:

```
public abstract class SortingStrategy : IComparer<Person>
{
    public static readonly SortingStrategy ByAgeDescending = ...;
    public static readonly SortingStrategy ByAgeAscending = ...;
    public static readonly SortingStrategy ByIncomeDescending = ...;
    public static readonly SortingStrategy ByIncomeAscending = ...;

    private SortingStrategy() {}

    private class ByAgeStrategy : SortingStrategy { ... }
    private class ByIncomeStrategy : SortingStrategy { ... }
}
```

Here the private constructor prevents any *other* subclasses, but the private nested classes can still subclass it as they have access to the constructor.

You can then make your method take a `SortingStrategy` instead of just an `IComparer<T>`.

Of course, using LINQ may well be more flexible in the longer term, as James suggested. It depends on what your goals are.

Comment: But what's preventing someone to use another `IComparer` than the ones available in the enum?

Comment: @ken2k: See my edit. (It's not clear whether the OP's goal is to force a limited selection, or just make some selections easily available.)

Comment: Great update, this solves the issue (even if you're right, it wasn't clear if the OP wanted to limit the sort selection). But is this really a best practice? I mean, I [often](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscy145f.aspx) [saw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sortorder.aspx) built-in .Net methods that take an enum as parameter?

Comment: @ken2k: It depends on the situation. The above sort of "smart enum" can be really handy when there's behaviour associated with each object. In other cases, just an enum is fine.

Comment: Great answer, this was my previous approach but the "enum of instances" idea popped into my mind. And yes, I'd like to force the caller to use one of those "ready to eat" strategies.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn’t allow having enums of arbitrary data types (VB.NET kind of does, with a hack). But you can simply declare the individual sorting strategies as `static readonly` fields of your `SortingStrategies` class, and make them implement `IComparable`.

On the other hand, you’ve now hard-coded the sorting strategies. This may be perfectly acceptable in some scenarios but I’d be wary since it’s not cleanly extensible.

Comment: "C# doesn’t allow having enums of arbitrary data types" Thanks for the clarification. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here you will end up having a switch or if block which is ugly in terms of code reusability/scalability. Here it would be much better to use the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

So for a sorting example of the Strategy Pattern

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DoFactory.GangOfFour.Strategy.RealWorld
{
  /// <summary>
  /// MainApp startup class for Real-World 
  /// Strategy Design Pattern.
  /// </summary>
  class MainApp
  {

    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point into console application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
      // Two contexts following different strategies
      SortedList studentRecords = new SortedList();

      studentRecords.Add("Samual");
      studentRecords.Add("Jimmy");
      studentRecords.Add("Sandra");
      studentRecords.Add("Vivek");
      studentRecords.Add("Anna");

      studentRecords.SetSortStrategy(new QuickSort());
      studentRecords.Sort();

      studentRecords.SetSortStrategy(new ShellSort());
      studentRecords.Sort();

      studentRecords.SetSortStrategy(new MergeSort());
      studentRecords.Sort();

      // Wait for user
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'Strategy' abstract class
  /// </summary>
  abstract class SortStrategy
  {
    public abstract void Sort(List<string> list);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
  /// </summary>
  class QuickSort : SortStrategy
  {
    public override void Sort(List<string> list)
    {
      list.Sort(); // Default is Quicksort
      Console.WriteLine("QuickSorted list ");
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
  /// </summary>
  class ShellSort : SortStrategy
  {
    public override void Sort(List<string> list)
    {
      //list.ShellSort(); not-implemented
      Console.WriteLine("ShellSorted list ");
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A 'ConcreteStrategy' class
  /// </summary>
  class MergeSort : SortStrategy
  {
    public override void Sort(List<string> list)
    {
      //list.MergeSort(); not-implemented
      Console.WriteLine("MergeSorted list ");
    }     
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The 'Context' class
  /// </summary>
  class SortedList
  {
    private List<string> _list = new List<string>();
    private SortStrategy _sortstrategy;

    public void SetSortStrategy(SortStrategy sortstrategy)
    {
      this._sortstrategy = sortstrategy;
    }

    public void Add(string name)
    {
      _list.Add(name);
    }

    public void Sort()
    {
      _sortstrategy.Sort(_list);

      // Iterate over list and display results
      foreach (string name in _list)
        Console.WriteLine(" " + name);
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

For more information on this pattern and explanation of the above code see http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx.

I hopw this helps.

Comment: Thx, the idea was to use the enum to implement a strategy pattern. But apparently it's not possible to create an enum of instances.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily add *extension method* (in case if `myObject` is of some system type), like

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObjectType>SortCollection(this MyObjectType myObject, SortingStrategies sotrStrategy) 
{
   ....
}
```

and use this like

```
MyObjectType myObject = new .... 
myObject.Sort(SortingStrategies.ByAgeDesc);
```

In case where `myObject` is **non** system type, just add a new function to *your* type.

Answer (score 0):

An enum value cannot be an `IComparer`. However, you can create a static class:

```
public static class SortingStrategies{

  static SortingStrategies() {
    ByAgeDesc = new ByAgeDescComparer();
    ByAgeAsc = new ByAgeAscComparer();
    ByIncomeDesc = new ByIncomeDescComparer()
  }

  public static IComparer ByAgeDesc { get; private set; }

  public static IComparer ByAgeAsc { get; private set; }

  public static IComparer ByIncomeDesc { get; private set; }

}
```

You can reference the desired `IComparer` like this:

```
SortingStrategies.ByIncomeDesc
```